# SQL - Merging planned vs actual tables with a date criteria in the planned table. for Power BI

Tags: sql, database, database-design, powerbi

I have a general question, with regards to planned and actual tables and their merging.

I have a planned table for products and their amounts, and the same for what really exists(actual). There are gaps on both sides, as in, not every planned has an actual and not every actual has a planned. I used a select union to combine the two tables, and I created another column called "type" where I then labeled the figures actual or planned. However I feel that is not a good way of doing things. I also should add that I have a data criteria with the planned table.

Is there a good way of structuring an SQL for the merging of the two tables to view in Power BI??

Comment: If you have a lots of plans (this can be quite common), then it's better to have a column with the plan name, and another column with the value. But there are many factors that go into the "best" way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @msta42a. The secret was simply creating a common key.

I also found that having the two columns in seprate columns rather, than in the same column and seperated by a "type" was easier to deal with in Power BI, especially with regards to creating a trand column or comparison of the two.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is look good, merging 2 tables with a additional column to identify planned/actual, what final output you are planning that matter the most,
if you have achieve your result by doing this, then it is good method.

Comment: well, it seems in Power BI it is better for me to compare the actual and planned if I have them in two seperate columns rather than the same column but with a different "type". Is there a general rule with regards to things like that, in datrabase design"?

Comment: create a KEY in both tables based on Date and Product, then you can create a relationship in powerbi.